# Can difflib be used to make a plagiarism detection program?

Tags: python, diff, difflib

I am trying to figure this out...

Can the `difflib.*` library in Python be used to make some kind of plagiarism detection program? If so how?

Maybe anyone could help me to figure out this question.

Comment: difflib will hardly be sufficient to come up with something that is actually usable in practice.

Answer (score 1):

It could be used, but you're going to face all the same general issues you find in [automated plagiarism detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plagiarism_detection).  It might give you a little bit of a head start on implementing some of the algorithms you need, but I don't think it is likely to take you very far.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes.

The long answer is that it will be a lot of work and you'll probably find that you'd be better using another language or an off-the-shelf tool, depending on the vast amount of sources you're likely to be referencing.