# Wcopyfind for python - plagiarism software?

Tags: python, text, analysis

Is there anything like wcopyfind for python?

http://plagiarism.bloomfieldmedia.com/z-wordpress/software/wcopyfind/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inbuilt difflib might help
http://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html

But people seem to think this is tough
[Can difflib be used to make a plagiarism detection program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312982/can-difflib-be-used-to-make-a-plagiarism-detection-program)